# ItemizedOverlay Feedback

Tags: android, android-maps

I have an `ItemizedOverlay` which I add to a `MapView` which is displayed inside a `Fragment`.

What I want to do is be able to feed back to the `Fragment` when the overlay's `onTap` method is called. So in iOS I would create a delegate and make the `Fragment` the delegate of the overlay. How should I do it in android??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone that has this problem or something along these lines, the route you want to take is broadcasting an `intent` which is then picked up by a `broadcast receiver`. When this receiver picks it up it then communicates back to its owner.